# Databricks CSV multiple read

Tags: python, databricks

Suppose I am having the following csv files with the following contents

**file_20190901.csv**

```
col1       col2         col3
data       20190901     A
```

**file_20190902.csv**

```
col1       col2         col3
data       20190901     B
data       20190902     A
```

So somedays later, having filename  file_20190903.csv will have

```
col1    col2         col3
data       20190902     B
data       20190903     A
```

So the tasks now is to merge these csv files in the data frame , and including all the records 20190901 to 20190903 on col2 , and using the lastest row data . So desire the results to be

```
col1    col2         col3
data    20190901     B 
data    20190902     B
data    20190903     A
```

How to do this in Databricks using Python ?

Answer (score 1):

From the sample files, col2 has the same values but col3 has different values. So, you cannot merge both the files.

**file_20190901.csv**

col1       col2         col3

data       20190901     A

**file_20190902.csv**

col1       col2         col3

data       20190901     B

**How to read multiple csv files:**

Copy all the csv files to the dbfs as shown:

[image]

Then create a python notebook and run as follows:

```
ReadMultiple = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/sample/*.csv")
display(ReadMultiple)
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: but the requirement is need to merge

Comment: From the sample files, col2 has the same values but col3 has different values. So, you cannot merge both the files.